# WKWebView property "plugInsEnabled": where is it good for?

Tags: wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

The `WKWebView` control has a property **`plugInsEnabled`** as part of the `preferences` of the `configuration` property of the said control. The documentation states:

> A Boolean value indicating whether plug-ins are enabled.

Apparently the documentalist didn't know it either. I can't find any other documentation of this setting.

Does anybody know what this setting exactly does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `plugInsEnabled` enables Safari compatible plugins, like Flash and Java, to work within the WKWebView component.